# Using two columns in the sub function in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a Data Table with two Text columns. I need to use column **b** to determine which letters to replace in column **a** with an "x".

I can do it using a for loop as in the code below. however my actual data set has 250,000+ rows so the script takes ages. Is there a more efficient way to do this? I considered lappy but couldn't get my head round it.

```
 DT <- data.table(a = c("ABCD","ABCD","ABCD","ABCD"), b = c("A","B","C", "D"))

DT$c <- ""

for (i in 1 : NROW(DT)){

  DT[i]$c <- sub(DT[i,b], "x", DT[i,a])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using the tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

DT <- data.table::data.table(a = c("ABCD","ABCD","ABCD","ABCD"), b = c("A","B","C", "D"))

DT %>% 
  mutate(new_vec = str_replace_all(string = a,pattern = b,replacement = "X"))
```

Comment: Thank you! str_replace_all did exactly what I needed in a fraction of the time!